# Django Queries: related subquery

Tags: sql, django, subquery, django-queryset

I have 3 Models: Offer, Request and Assignment. Assignment makes a connection between Request and Offer. Now I want to do this:

```
select *
from offer as a
where places > (
    select count(*)
    from assignment
    where offer_id = a.id and
    to_date > "2014-07-07");
```

I am not quiet sure how to achieve this with a django QuerySet... Any tips?

Edit: The query above is just an example, how the query in general should look like. The django model looks like this:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    ...
    places = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class Request(models.Model):
    ...

class Assignment(models.Model):
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_data = models.DateField()
    request = models.ForeignKey("Request",related_name="assignments")
    offer = models.ForeignKey("Offer",related_name="assignments")
```

People now can create a offer with a given amount of places or a request. The admin then will connect a request with an offer for a given time. This is saved as an assignment. The query above should give me a list of offers, which have still places left. Therefore I want to count the number of valid assignments for a given offer to compare it with its number of places. This list should be used to find a possible offer for a given request to create a new assignment.

I hope this describes the problem better.

Comment: What is the relations between offer request and assignment and the model fields of three of this?

Comment: I added a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately related subqueries aren't directly supported by ORM operations. Usage of `.extra(where=...)` should be possible in this case.

To get the same results without using a subquery something like the following should work:

```py
Offer.objects.filter(
    assignment__to_date__gt=thedate
).annotate(
    assignment_cnt=Count('assignment')
).filter(
    assignment_cnt__lte=F('places')
)
```

The exact query depends on the model definitions.

Comment: The second method produces an `OUTER JOIN` query and is therefore more efficient than any method involving a subquery. Given that this method also avoids any raw sql in a `raw` or `extra` call, this method is definitely the preferred way to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score -1):

```
query = '''select *
from yourapp_offer as a
where places > (
    select count(*)
    from yourapp_assignment
    where offer_id = a.id and
    to_date > "2014-07-07");'''

offers = Offer.objects.raw(query):
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/

Comment: why -1? It is the **only** way to do that (((: